# How to change authorizationRedirectStrategy in OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth, spring-security-oauth2

I want to manipulate the redirect URL that is sent to my OAuth provider so that it redirects to a different URL before redirecting to the authentication URL for my app (multi-tenant wildcard subdomain)

Is there a way to configure a different `authorizationRedirectStrategy` in `OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver`? Currently it is initialized with `new DefaultRedirectStrategy()`

Or do I have to completely instantiate the `OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver` "per hand" instead of creating it via `oauth2Login()` configuration?

Comment: The `authenticationRedirectStrategy` is final and, therefore, can't be changed. You can provide a custom implementation of `OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver` or change the `authorizationRequestUri` in your configuration. See the [reference docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/client/authorization-grants.html#_initiating_the_authorization_request).

Comment: I tried to implement a custom `OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver` but then the method `org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter#matchesAuthorizationResponse` fails because the redirectUri does not match